# About the parameter defined in process(...) method of Processor interface

Tags: java, java-annotations

In `javax.annotation.processing` package there is a interface `Processor` in which there is a function:

```
/**
     * Processes a set of annotation types on type elements
     * originating from the prior round and returns whether or not
     * these annotation types are claimed by this processor.  If {@code
     * true} is returned, the annotation types are claimed and subsequent
     * processors will not be asked to process them; if {@code false}
     * is returned, the annotation types are unclaimed and subsequent
     * processors may be asked to process them.  A processor may
     * always return the same boolean value or may vary the result
     * based on chosen criteria.
     *
     * <p>The input set will be empty if the processor supports {@code
     * "*"} and the root elements have no annotations.  A {@code
     * Processor} must gracefully handle an empty set of annotations.
     *
     * @param annotations the annotation types requested to be processed
     * @param roundEnv  environment for information about the current and prior round
     * @return whether or not the set of annotation types are claimed by this processor
     */
    boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                    RoundEnvironment roundEnv);
```

The Java API `AbstractProcessor` implements above interface.  Now I created my own processor class:

```
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
   ...
   @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        for (TypeElement annotation: annotations) {
            // How can I get the class of the annotation ?
        }
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. The API doc tells me the `annotations` in the process function are

> the the annotation types requested to be processed

Then, why is it with type `TypeElement` not `java.lang.annotation.Annotation` ? I get confused by this because I am not sure whether the `annotations` actually mean the elements that being annotated or the real annotations annotating elements.

2. Because of my 1st question above, how can I get each annotation's class from the `TypeElement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a package [`javax.lang.model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/package-summary.html) which follows a mirror-based design described in [Mirrors: Design Principles for Meta-level Facilities of
Object-Oriented Programming Languages](https://bracha.org/mirrors.pdf). It's a greatly designed abstraction used in (but not limited to) the annotation processing framework.

1. > Then, why is it with type `TypeElement` not `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`?

   When you design a framework, it's important to keep it [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) (available for extension). You never know what future versions of the language will bring. You need to stay flexible assuming a new form of metadata may appear.

   > I get confused by this because I am not sure whether the annotations actually mean the elements that being annotated or the real annotations annotating elements.

   It's "the real annotations annotating elements" since you are processing annotation types.

   ```
   for (TypeElement typeElement : annotations) {
       // it's likely the ElementKind.ANNOTATION_TYPE
       typeElement.getKind();

       // elements annotated with the annotation
       environment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(typeElement);
   }
   ```
2. > Because of my 1st question above, how can I get each annotation's class from the `TypeElement`?

   The `TypeElement` *represents* your annotation class.

To read:

1. https://bracha.org/mirrors.pdf (it will take a lot of time to process)
2. https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder (it's a simple annotation processor)
3. https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/core/AnnotationProcessor.java (it's a good [practical](https://projectlombok.org/) example)
4. The Javadoc of [the package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/package-summary.html) and the core classes such as [`Processor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html), [`AnnotatedConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/AnnotatedConstruct.html), [`Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html), [`TypeElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html), [`TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you misunderstand my 2nd question. I know `TypeElement` represents annotation class but it is not annotation class. I mean how can I get the `Class` instance of my annotation. For example if I have a custom annotation `@MyAnnotation`, I want to get `MyAnnotation.class` from the `TypeElement`, is it possible?

Comment: About your answer to my 1st question. I also know the open-close principle, but `Annotation` is a interface, it is not a concrete implementation of anything. I still look for a convincing reason why `Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations` is not a `Set<? extends Annotation>`  type in its design & variable name is saing `annotations`. Besides, you missed my question that I wonder whether that set is representing all my custom annotations or all elements annotated by my annotations.

Comment: @Leem.fin `java.lang.Annotation` isn't a part of the `javax.lang.model` abstraction (that's why it's `Set<? extends TypeElement>`) and I guess `annotations` is used in [a broader sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) (it doesn't necessarily refer to the `Annotation` interface we know). Note that the Javadoc can be changed easily not effecting source code.

Comment: @Leem.fin I included it ("the real annotations annotating elements"): it's your annotations. To get elements annotated with your annotations you need an environment and you do `environment.getElementsAnnotatedWith` (see the snippet above)

Comment: *"representing all my custom annotations"* is a bit inaccurate. *"representing all the annotations I support (or my annotation processor supports)"* is more precise (see [`@SupportedAnnotationTypes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/SupportedAnnotationTypes.html))

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the links in your answer, it is more clear to me now :) .

Comment: @Leem.fin you're welcome. I will add an example of a custom processor a bit later today